# ERROR Error: MatSortHeader must be provided with a unique id

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm attempting to implement some Angular material sorting, however I'm receiving the error telling me that each mat sort header must be provided with a unique id.

I'm not quite sure what this is referencing, and I can't find anything about this online.

Here's the template snippet:

```html
<div class="headers"
     matSort
     (matSortChange)="sortDocuments($event)">
  <span class="col-3">
    <label id="file-name-header"
           class="header" 
           [mat-sort-header]="documentsList?.model?.fileParts[0]?.meta?.name">File Name</label>
  </span>
  <span class="col-2">
    <label id="file-type-header"
           class="header"
           [mat-sort-header]="documentsList?.model?.type">File Type</label>
  </span>
  <span class="col-3">
    <label id="user-header"
           class="header"
           [mat-sort-header]="documentsList?.model?.user">User</label>
  </span>
  <span class="col-2">
    <label id="file-size-header"
           class="header"
           [mat-sort-header]="documentsList?.model?.fileParts[0]?.meta?.size">File Size</label>
  </span>
  <span class="col-1">
    <label id="date-header"
           class="header"
           [mat-sort-header]="documentsList?.model?.fileParts[0]?.createdDate">Created Date</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

The MatSortModule is imported in the module, and the component code at the moment is largely trivial.

I'm attempting to just log the sort event I'm capturing from the headers:

```js
public sortDocuments(sort: Sort) {
    console.log('sort event: %o', sort);
}
```

The curious thing is that clicking the sortable headers logs this:

`sort event: {active: undefined, direction: "asc"}`, whereas in the past, the `active` property has always been the field I'd been sorting on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was a silly mistake, but I think it's valuable to live here:

I had expected the content inside the `[mat-sort-header]=""` to represent the object path of the field I am sorting within my `*ngFor` block of data, not shown because it was trivial and just contained `{{ field.paths }}`.

In order to get the expected behavior, all the `[mat-sort-header]=""` blocks needed to be declared as strings:

`[mat-sort-header]="'documentsList.model.type'">`

notice the extra `'`'s.  Doing that allowed the logging of the sort event to correctly display the various field names when they were clicked, instead of undefined.

Logger now:

`sort event: {active: "documentsList.model.type", direction: "asc"}`